# Displaying result of first array in array_diff

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter. 
I want difference of two array as I am using `array_diff` function of php.
Due to associative array, I have used `call_user_func_array` and I got record.

```
$result_sun = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data['sun_holiday']);
$result_sat = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $data['third_sat']);
```

But when I am going to make difference of these two array like,

```
$result = array_diff($result_sun,$result_sat);
```

It only shows the record of first array `$result_sun`.

```
$result_sun = Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-06
    [1] => 2015-09-13
    [2] => 2015-09-20
    [3] => 2015-09-27
)

$result_sat = Array
(
    [0] => 2015-09-19
)
```

So, why the difference is not occurring??

Comment: Your only argument to array_merge is 1 array? WHat are you trying to do with array merge if you feed it only 1 array?

Comment: paste both the arrays and the expected output

Comment: Check the docs for [array_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php)


It states that only values in the 1st array will be returned if they are not found in the other array(s).


It does not perform a `diff` like you would expect using `git diff` or similar commands.

Comment: "*Due to associative array, I have used call_user_func_array**... uh, what?? Not sure what you're trying to do there, but if you just want the values in a numbered array, try `$result_sun=array_values($data['sun_holiday']);`

Answer (score 1):

```
$result1 = array_diff($result_sun,$result_sat);
$result2 = array_diff($result_sat,$result_sun);

$result=array_merge($result1,$result2);
```

Compares $result_sun against one or more other arrays and returns the values in $result_sun that are not present in any of the other arrays.
so take difference of both and then merge it will be good if you put your code then we can give more accurate answer